# Insertar datos en un array desde formulario

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario para poder ingresar 10 datos en una tabla. Le he añadido un botón de para poder hacer la operación. Lo que quiero es ir añadiendo esos datos en un array para poder mostrarlos luego, pero solo me muestra `Array ( [dato] => )`. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Código HTML:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
      <form action="#" method="post">
        <table border="1" style="margin: 0 auto;">
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Study</th>
          </tr>
          <?php
            for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
              echo "<tr>
                <td>".$i."</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='dato'></td>
              </tr>";
            }
          ?>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="datos" value="Generate">
      </form>
    </div>
```

Código PHP

```
 <?php
          if (isset($_POST['dato'])) {

            $dato = $_POST['dato'];

            $datos = array('dato' => $dato);

            print_r($datos);
          };
        ?>
```

Comment: el código del formulario y el php estan en el mismo archivo o separados?

Comment: creo que lo que necesitas es cambiar `<td><input type='text' name='dato'></td>` por `<td><input type='text' name='dato[]'></td>`, ya que quieres enviar 10 datos a la vez, debes enviarlo como array.

Comment: @Aprendiz Sí, están en el mismo formulario